# React component state only changes in DevTools hooks not in front or console.logs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, use-state

I'm adding pagination for the list of items I get through GraphQl query. I've managed to get everything sorted however for the past day one single state has decided to bug me.

I use start and limit as query options to paginate. Let's say the limit of items is always 5

On component mount I set initial values:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setPartStart(0)
        setPartLimit(5)
        setCurrentPage(1)
    },[])
```

Now, when I get a total count of parts through different query, I'm calling a following function:

```
 const calculatePages = () => {
        setPages([])
        let rawNumOfPages = numberOfParts.partsCount / partLimit
        let roundedNumOfPages = Math.ceil(rawNumOfPages)
        setNumOfPages(roundedNumOfPages)
        for(let page = 1; page <= roundedNumOfPages; page++) {
            setPages(prevState => [...prevState, <button key={page} value={page} className={`${currentPage === page ? 'active' : 'pagination--box'}`} onClick={(e) => {selectPage(e)}}>{page}</button>])
        }
    }
```

It is calculating a total number of pages from the total count of parts and the selected limit. Then in the for loop I'm outputting a button element for each page for navigation purposes. Then I output that navigation array of buttons as {pages} in a div

The issue is when I call selectPage function from onClick in button element:

```
    const selectPage = (e) => {
        let actualPage = parseInt(e.target.value)
        if(actualPage > currentPage) {
            setPartStart(prevState => parseInt(prevState + partLimit))
            setCurrentPage(actualPage)
            console.log(currentPage)
        } else if(actualPage < currentPage) {
            setPartStart(prevState => prevState - partLimit)
            setCurrentPage(actualPage)
            console.log(currentPage)
        }
    }
```

Here I'm getting a number of page that has been clicked through e.target.value and then compare it to the currentPage, if the new one is bigger then I set start value for GraphQl query to prevState + limit, if the new one is lower then I set start value to be prevState - limit.

The issue is that the currentPage is always 1, even though in DevTools it is changing when I look at Components explorer. These console.logs always put out 1.
Due to async nature of useState I would expect that the currentPage updates to 2 when I click on 3 but it doesn't, it stays on 1 in these console logs (there is also a condition to add class active to the button if the currentPage === Page but that too stays always on 1).
Correct state in the DevTools hooks sidebar only puzzled me more.

Any help is welcomed, Thanks

Comment: `console.log` directly after a `setState` call will still log the value of the *current* render.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for the reply. Well I expected that it will "display" the previous value i.e. when I click 2 it will still be 1 but when I click 3 it will rerender and have 2 because it was updated between console.log and another click. This wasn't the case, the useEffect was useful and I had to introduce another state variable clickedPage and it worked. Thanks again.